# I modified sudoers. All users can not use sudo now. How should I fix this?

Tags: password, sudo

I was trying to save times to type password for `sudo` because one of my scripts had to be randomly repeated quite often.  I googled some information about how to bypass typing password and applied to my server.  Now the sudo account is corrupted and all the users on server cant not use `sudo`.  How can I fix this?

What I did:

- I created `mysudoers` in `/etc/sudoers.d/`

  `sudo vim /etc/sudoers.d/mysudoers`
- Added my account in `mysudoers`

  `rna ALL = NOPASSWD: ~/scripts/getLog`
- save & exit
- chmod

  `sudo chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/mysudoers`

Error log when I type `sudo` :

```
rna@rna-P580:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo                                                               
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/mysudoers: syntax error near line 0 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/mysudoers near line 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: Look at the linked question and edit that file to replace `~` with the path of your home directory (which would be something like `/home/rna`).

Comment: I fixed sudoers with `pkexec`. thanks for the link @muru